# Camera - Camera triangulation vs PnP

Tags: math, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration, triangulation

I'm trying to find pose of a calibration target and we do have a stereo system. I think there are two ways by which you can get the pose of the target with respect to camera 1, say.

Method 1:
Find the points in camera 1 and camera 2 and do ray - ray triangulation.

Method 2:
Use camera 1 and find the pose using PnP.

There is a significant difference between the two poses. On x, y they differ by 50um and z differs by 1.4mm. Resolution of the cameras are 20um. And this difference varies with different poses.

May I know why? Or is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your camera calibration (intrinsics or extrinsics) is likely at fault here.

Of the two methods, the second one is likely more accurate, since it is not affected by matching, baseline (extrinsics), and triangulation errors. But of course, if you are interested in doing stereo, you will need to understand and correct the source of the errors you observe.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you think it is possible to correct those errors? Or we will always have some error because of triangulation?